# Resharper parameters indentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I believe formating like below is default in ReSharper (assuming new lines were added manually)

```
foo.LenghtyNamedProperty.Bar(x,
                             y,
                            );
```

Is it possible in ReSharper to achive indentation reset if opening parenthesis is follwed by new line?

```
foo.LenghtyNamedProperty.Bar(
    x,
    y
);
```

Answer (score 5):

What helped me was to turn off "First call arguments by '('".

This is at 
Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Tabs, Indents, Alignment > Align Multiline Constructs

Answer (score 1):

If you mean only to pull the arguments to the left (and you decide the line breaks), go to `Resharper >> Options >> c# >> Formatting style >> Other >> Align Multiline Constructs >> Call arguments` and uncheck it.

If you want to enforce this policy, go to `Resharper >> Options >> c# >> Formatting style >> Line Breaks and Wrapping >> Line Wrapping >> Wrap invocation arguments` and set it to `Chop always` and check `Prefer wrap after "(" in invocation`.

The paths work for `Resharper Ultimate 2017.2.2`.